# PyTorch: ImportError: libcurand.so.9.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I tried to install PyTorch==0.4.1 with Anaconda.

I tried using the command "conda install pytorch=0.4.1 torchvision==0.2.1 cuda91 -c pytorch" and "conda install pytorch=0.4.1 torchvision==0.2.1 cuda90 -c pytorch", but both installation will result in the error

```
ImportError: libcurand.so.9.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when importing torch.

Also, running "locate libcurand.so.9.1" gives me

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1.85
```

I just couldn't figure out what caused the problem and how to fix it..

(CUDA in the system is version 9.1, although I think Anaconda install its own CUDA toolkit)

Comment: Why don't you try newest pytorch version and see if the problem persist? It's currently `1.4.0`, `0.4.1` is legacy